# Can the REST API-get response be changed before it is used by angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, security, local-storage

I have a angular application, I am getting user information when the user logs in through REST-API call.

Can the response data be changed before it is used by browser let's say storing the data in the localstorage.

```
localStorage.setItem(data_response)
```

Can the localstorage get different values than those sent by the server.

Is there some way to modify the response by some hacking tool.

Comment: Of course: you can create own objects and then extract data from the response and set them within your new object, using a service or whatsoever.

Comment: You can use RXJS operators to modify your response, after the API call and when you get back the response.

Comment: I take it that the question is related to the security of the data when consumed by an angular (or any other client) application. In that case yes, the response from the server can be manipulated, probably easiest is through an interception proxy but the attacker could also modify the client application to modify the data. If the transfer between client and the API is not appropriately encrypted the attacker can also manipulate the data while in transit. In short: do not trust client applications.